# Write a custom spark datagrid component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am a newbie and really stuck with this. The company I just started working for has a full MVC based application written using Flex and we have our own component library which was written using Flex 3 and these are all MX components. Now I am asked to slowly start migrating our components to Spark?

I searched everywhere on internet. There are a lot of articles on how to moving the applications to Flex 4.5 but no article on what would be the step to write a custom spark component from a mx component? As far as my research goes the only difference between mx and spark is the css layouting for both components is different.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This is actually pretty well documented in the official AS3 docs. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-8000.html

Comment: You're a newbie and you've been asked to write custom components? And a datagrid at that. Please have someone explain to your manager that you have to get to know the framework first before diving into the more advanced stuff.